Can I prevent Ableton resetting MIDI devices when another MIDI device is turned on?
I have a Lunchpad Mk3.  If I switch it to (for example) sequencer mode, then turn on another midi device (a synth for example), the launchpad will go back to session mode.  I've talked with Novation and the tech helped me narrow down the issue to Ableton.  Is there anything to do to prevent this from happening?

If you're into programming, it might be possible to mess around with the controller script. I'm not sure if that's still possible, but it used to be so that every control surface had a Python script handling it, and there were de-compiled versions of the scripts somewhere out there that you could customize.
